# How to get DataGridRow cell value?

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently have this method set up to detect double clicks on each row in my DataGrid:

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)sender;
        DataRow dr = (DataRow)row.DataContext;
        string value = dr[0].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(value);
    }
```

My problem though is I can't seem to get cell values. As you can see I tried to get the value of the first cell in the row but it would just crash. Any ideas how I can do this? :)

Comment: How does it crash? Is there an error message?

Comment: Delete all that and start reading [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx). There's no such thing as *"get the DataGridRow cell value"* in WPF, there is only DataBinding and proper separation between UI and data. You can't *"get the DataGridRow cell value"* because the UI's responsibility is to *show* data, not to *hold* it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dataGrid, int row, int column)
{
    DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(dataGrid, row);
    if (rowContainer != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

        // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
        if (cell == null)
        {
            // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
            dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dataGrid.Columns[column]);

            cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
        }

        return cell;
    }

    return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example of what HighCore mentioned:

Here I have a list of objects ( with type EntitySet ), and I set that as the ItemsSource for the dataGrid.  Then in the double-click I just cast the SelectedItem as an EntitySet.

```
  public List<EntitySet> EntitySets { get; set; }

  public EntitySetsForm( List<EntitySet> entitySets )
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     EntitySets = entitySets;
     dataGrid.ItemsSource = entitySets;
  }

  private void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
  {
     EntitySet entitySet = dataGrid.SelectedItem as EntitySet;
     if ( entitySet == null ) return;
```